# Why is mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() less than getDuration() when it is completed?

Tags: android

```
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

When the mediaPlayer is playing,

```
    //100 milliseconds
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

But the seekBar can not seekTo the max,

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            LogUtil.d(TAG, "CurrentPosition = " + mp.getCurrentPosition(+ " -- Duration = " + mp.getDuration());
        }
    });
```

I found that the mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() is always less than mediaPlayer.getDuration().If I use seekBar.setProgress(mp.getDuration()) when it is completed, the seekBar animation is not smooth.

So why is getCurrentPosition() less than getDuration() when it is completed?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Do you have more code than just what you've pasted? Also, what units are you measuring in - just in seconds? Can you show post the return value for both methods?

Comment: [getCurrentPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition())
is always less than
[getDuration](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration())
also when the playback is completed.
Thanks for helping me and sorry for so late to reply!